# How can I populate a dropdown list with a field from my database?

Tags: angularjs

I am referencing a database like so:

```
$scope.dbevent = $scope.env.database('test.event');
```

The 'test.event' database has mutliple fields. Here's a basic layout:
[table layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ti6BB.png)

If I wanted to create a dropdown list that just shows the contents of say the "Performed By" field, how would I do so? For more clarification, the "Performed By" data is populated somewhere else, and contains a list of names. I just need to put all of these names in a selection list.

I'm assuming the use of `<select>`, but am not sure how to set up the `ng-options` part

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_select.asp

Comment: Now I see. I'll just have to make a solid function to populate my data in an array first. I was trying to skip a step without realizing it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can populate your drop down using by populating array in your controller and iterate over it using ng-options

```
<select ng-model="selectModel"  ng-options="item for item in yourList" ></select>
```

Comment: Ah okay I was approaching this in a weird way. This makes sense. I was basically trying to skip a step without realizing it, but I'll have to populate an array first with the data I need. Thanks for the help!